# Distinguish ascii from UTF-8 characters in the same file

Tags: text-processing, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

On Ubuntu 18.04, I created a dummy text file with just one UTF-8 character, `è`. The other characters are all `ascii`:

```
$ cat dummytext
Hello
Helloè
```

This is the resulting `hexdump`:

```
$ hexdump -C dummyfile
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a 48 65  6c 6c 6f c3 a8 0a        |Hello.Hello...|
0000000e
```

The file is identified as

```
$ file dummyfile
dummyfile2: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Each character is represented by a *single* byte, *except for* the UTF-8 `è` character, which is `c3a8`, so it is represented by 2 bytes. How can the file contents be correctly interpreted, if the number of bytes used to represent each character is not constant?

My guess: maybe the parser, when encountering a hex value which is greater than the last `ascii` character `7F` (and this is the case of `c3`), is forced to read at least another byte, to determine the right character to be printed?

Comment: I think that you haven't quite expressed the question that you mean to ask.  Your question seems actually to be two questions: _How does `file` know that this is UTF-8, when it could instead be an old 8-bit encoding?_ followed by _How does a UTF-8 decoder know where multiple-byte sequences begin and end?_.

Comment: @JdeBP Maybe unconsciously the actual questions were the ones you wrote (even if I just used `file` as a further verification). DopeGhoti's answer fits to the second one. For the first one, maybe `file` looks for bytes "whose high order bit is set" and then is able to guess if there is an UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the BSD manual, section 5, the page on UTF8 reads:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The UTF-8 encoding represents UCS-4 characters as a sequence of octets, using between 1 and 6 for each character.  It is backwards
>   compatible with ASCII, so `0x00`-`0x7f` refer to the ASCII character set.
>
> The multibyte encoding of non-ASCII characters consist entirely of bytes whose high order bit is set.  The actual encoding is
>   represented by the following table:
>
> ```
>  [0x00000000 - 0x0000007f] [00000000.0bbbbbbb] -> 0bbbbbbb
>  [0x00000080 - 0x000007ff] [00000bbb.bbbbbbbb] -> 110bbbbb, 10bbbbbb
>  [0x00000800 - 0x0000ffff] [bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb] ->
>          1110bbbb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb
>  [0x00010000 - 0x001fffff] [00000000.000bbbbb.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb] ->
>          11110bbb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb
>  [0x00200000 - 0x03ffffff] [000000bb.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb] ->
>          111110bb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb
>  [0x04000000 - 0x7fffffff] [0bbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb.bbbbbbbb] ->
>          1111110b, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb, 10bbbbbb
> ```
>
> If more than a single representation of a value exists (for example, `0x00`; `0xC0 0x80`;`0xE0 0x80 0x80`), the shortest representation
>   is always used.  Longer ones are detected as an error as they pose a
>        potential security risk, and destroy the 1:1 character:octet sequence mapping.

From the Linux manual, section 7, the page on UTF8 similarly reads:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> [... UTF-8 is situationally better than UCS-2 in part because i]n addition, the majority of UNIX tools expect  ASCII  files  and  can't read 16-bit words as characters without major modifications. [...]
>
> The UTF-8 encoding of Unicode and UCS does not have these problems and is the common way in which Unicode is used on UNIX-style operating systems.
>
> **Properties**
>
> The UTF-8 encoding has the following nice properties:
>
> - UCS characters `0x00000000` to `0x0000007f` (the classic US-ASCII characters) are encoded simply as bytes `0x00` to `0x7f` (ASCII compatibility).  This means that files and strings which contain only 7-bit ASCII characters have the same encoding under both ASCII and UTF-8.

So it's not really possible to distinguish ASCII from UTF-8 because, in a UTF-8 file, ASCII *is* UTF-8.  `file` looks at the first 96KiB of a file and tries to determine what it is.  Because it sees more than zero UTF-8 code sequences, it determines the file to be UTF-8 because it is a strict superset of ASCII.

Comment: Thank you. In Ubuntu there is not the same manpage. The homologous one is in section 7, and it is not as concise and clear as yours, which can instead be found in [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=utf8&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports).

Comment: I've added a similar citation from the Linux manual (7) to go along with the BSD manual (5) one.